# When I write/read email, how can I see all past conversations with that person?

Tags: gmail

I'm looking for a 3rd party plugin for Gmail that will show me all the past emails that someone sent me.

When I respond to someone's email, I want to understand what I've said to her before.

Comment: Questions on Super User are expected to generally relate to computer software or computer hardware in some way, within the scope defined in the [faq](http://superuser.com/faq). Questions about Web Apps are considered off topic on Super User. Questions within this scope are better fit on a Q&A website like [Web Apps SE](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) - Please don't repost your question there, this one will automatically be migrated after closing. - Voting to close

Answer (score 1):

you can use the search bar to find all conversations with one person